# Top margin of an element (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I need to set a margin to the top of an element. The text must be within the element and have a top margin of N pixels.

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GRQNh/

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 960px;
}
.breadcrumbs {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 10%;
}
.name {
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can't set any margin-top or bottom on inline elements see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324527/margin-top-in-inline-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.breadcrumbs` has `position: relative`, set `position: absolute;` to `.name`.

- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GRQNh/20/)

Comment: thank you, I think it's the right answer.

Thank you all for your help!

(10 minutes for accept answer.)

Comment: Thing is, if you added some more content below it, the fresh content would not detect anything in there (because `.name` is absolutely positioned) and it will behave like `.breadcrumbs` were empty.

Answer (score 3):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GRQNh/17/)** or you may be try with padding-top instead margin-top as follows

```
.name {
    display:block;
    color: #000;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `display: inline-block;` to get the margin to work.

**For instance,**

```
.name {
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For it to work you will need to make the element behave like a **block** element. A block element can have, for instance, margins or paddings.

However, you will want to keep it from being displayed like an **actual block element**, so you will want to keep its visual displacement the same (that is, **inline**).

Luckily, there is a css value for `display` which does exactly what you need:

`display: inline-block;`

Add this to the span (which is `inilne` by default) and it will behave like a `block` element while it will still look like an `inline` element.

You can also give up on margins at all and use `padding-top: 50px`.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, you must specify the parent ELEMENT position relative and absolute position subsidiary and specify top: 0;

Answer (score 0):

the `<span>` is an inline element. That means you cant apply margin or padding to it.

For the solution to your problem you have -at least- two options.

1.Change the container of your text to a block element, like `<div>`

so:

```
<span class="name">Name</span>
```

will become

```
<div class="name">Name</div>
```

2.Change the behavior of your `span` by making it a block or inline-block element with this css:

```
.name {
display:inline-block
/* rest of your css */
```

These two articles will give you a good idea of what is inline and block

http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/